# How do I close only one specific Excel workbook?

Tags: python, excel, pywin32

I have two opened workbooks. Workbooks are opened manually not in COM! So I don't have already existing object to close. `Workbooks.Open` can't help with that and gives me an error. How do I close specific workbook in python which was opened manually by mouse?

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
excel = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.Visible = False

excel.DisplayAlerts = False

excel.Workbooks('1.xlsx').Close()
excel.Quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Found [this VBA stuff](https://bettersolutions.com/excel/workbooks/vba-closing.htm) and the Python bindings are pretty similar:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

xl = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
xl.Workbooks("FILENAME.EXT").Close(SaveChanges=True)
```

This totally works for me in Python 3.6, just thought I´d leave that here for others who stumble upon this via Google.